# Are there any performance penalties for running SMP enabled Linux kernel on a Uni processor (ARM Cortex A8 based SOC)?

Tags: linux-kernel, synchronization, arm, spinlock, cortex-a8

This is a two fold question that raised from my trivial observation that I am running a SMP enabled Linux on our ARM-Cortex 8 based SoC. First part is about performance (memory space/CPU time) difference between SMP and NON-SMP Linux kernel on a Uni processor system. Does any difference exits?

Second part is about use of Spinlock. AFAIK spinklock are noop in case uni-processor. Since there is only one CPU and only one process will be running on it (at a time ) there is no other process for busy-looping. So for synchronization I just need to disable interrupt for protecting my critical section. Is this understanding of mine correct?

Ignore portability of drivers factor for this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

A large amount of synchronisation code in the kernel compiles way to almost nothing in uni-processor kernels which descries the behaviour you describe.   Performance of n-way system is definitely not 2n - and gets worse as the number of CPUs.

You should continue to write your driver with using synchronisation mechanisms for SMP systems -  safe in the knowledge that you'll get the correct single-processor case when the kernel is configured for uni-processor.

Disabling interrupts globally is like taking a sledge-hammer to a nut - maybe just disabling pre-emption on the current CPU is enough - which the spinlock does even on uni-processor systems.

If you've not already done so, take a look at Chapter 5 of [Linux Device Drivers 3rd Edition](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch05.pdf) - there are a variety of spinlock options depending on the circumstance.

Comment: Please revise your statements, disabling preemption doesn't help in synchronization of ISR (IRQ handlers) and spinlocks DON'T  disable preempt, they disable IRQs.

Answer (score 1):

As you have stated that you are running the linux kernel as compiled in SMP mode on Uni-processor system so it's clear that you'll not get any benefit in terms of speed & memory.

As the linux-kernel uses **extensive locking** for synchronization. But it Uni-Processor mode there may be no need of locking theoretically but there are many cases where its necessary so try to use Locking where its needed but not as much as in SMP.

**but you should know it well that Spinlocks are implemented by set of macros, some prevent concurrency with IRQ handlers while the
other ones not.Spinlocks are suitable to protect small pieces of code which are intended to run
for a very short time.**

As of your second question, you are trying to remove spinlocks by disabling interrupts for Uni-Processor mode but **Spinlock macros are in non-preemptible UP(Uni-Processor) kernels evaluated to empty macros(or some of them to macros just disabling/enabling interrupts). UP kernels with
preemption enabled use spinlocks to disable preemption. For most purposes, pre-emption can be tought of as SMP equivalent.** so in UP kernels if you use Spinlocks then they will be just empty macro & i think it will be better to use it.

there are basically four technique for synchronization as..1->Nonpreemptability,2->Atomic Operations,3->Interrupt Disabling,4->Locks.

but as you are saying to disable interrupt for synchronization then remember Because of its simplicity, **interrupt disabling is used by kernel functions for implementing a critical region. 
This technique does not always prevent kernel control path interleaving.** 
Critical section should be short because any communication between CPU and I/O is blocked while a kernel control path is running in this section.

so if you need synchronization in Uni-Processor then use semaphore.

Comment: Was going to increment your answer until i read the last statement, viz.: "so if you need synchronization in Uni-Processor then use semaphore."
I disagree with that: semaphores (and now mutexes), are to be used *only* in process context as they work by having loser's sleep => calling schedule(). So, using a mutex in interrupt context would cause no end of issues, besides just being buggy!
So yeah, I'd summarize saying: pl continue to use the spinlock API even on UP, as they become light-weight dis-ablers of IRQs and preemption as required with no spinning overhead.

Comment: @kaiwan i think u are right!!! 
but as the question's point of view-->"So for synchronization I just need to disable interrupt for protecting my critical section." i have said to use semaphore because the user has disabled the IRQ...& as we know "the semaphore itself
could cause process to sleep and to schedule() another process to run. This is unwanted in IRQ handler, in which only spinlocks should be used."